# Binomial test for nested data

Tags: binomial-distribution, nested-data

I have 100 subjects who were scored on their performance in a series of trials (binary outcome for each trial: "hit" or "miss"). I want to find out whether overall there are more "hit" than "miss" trials. Since the trials are repeated for each individual (each subject has 4 trials), then the data  may not be independent. If so, do I still use a binomial test? Or is there are other analysis I can use?

Thank you very much. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Are you comparing groups or controlling for covariates?

Comment: Nope I am not. It's a pilot study so we just want to find out if frequency of hits and misses differ.

Comment: You refer to "hits" & "misses". Was this a signal detection study?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could add a random effect for subject in a GLM framework. For subject s, trial t let

$Y_{s,t} \sim Bernoulli(p_s), \quad p_s = logit(\theta + \beta_s), \quad \beta_s \sim N(0,\sigma_s^2)$.

Fitting this model would be pretty simple (using the R package lme4, for example).